# PostgreSQL pattern with numeric and varchar in a string

Tags: postgresql

I have column address in table and has the following data.Where I need to perform some specific operations.

address

```
RR 2 BOX 455
RR 1 BOX 32
RR 6 BOX 104
RT 1, BOX 33
RR 4 BOX 140
RR 6 BOX 340
1927 ABC AVE BOX 1662
HC 62 BOX 138-1

123 BOX RD
123 BOX ABC ROAD
123 ROAD BOX CT
123 BOX ROAD
8153 ABC ROAD BOX 36
13102 BOX ABC LN
```

In Input-1 set, I have data where I need to replace the BOX word and the following number with empty stringand 
in the Input-2 set, I have the data where I don't want to replace anything.

If you observe, I have numeric and varchar after the word BOX.So, I need to replace when it is a numeric only.

How can I perform the operations so that I get following result.

```
RR 2 
RR 1 
RR 6 
RT 1, 
RR 4 
RR 6 
1927 ABC AVE 
HC 62 

123 BOX ABC ROAD
123 BOX RD
123 ROAD BOX CT
123 BOX ROAD
8153 ABC ROAD BOX 36
13102 BOX ABC LN
```

I have tried some queries but, I didn't get the exact result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it:

```
regexp_replace(address, ' BOX \d+', '')
```